# Convert image downloaded into a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to download an image asynchronously from url and then convert it to a bitmap, I am able to download the image asynchronously without any error, but I am finding it difficult converting it to a bitmap.

**here is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // This is my image link
            String url="www.myimagelink.com";

            // This downloads the image from the servers
            new DownloadImage(ImageView).execute(url);

            //this is suppose to convert my bitmap into a byteArray, but I cant seem to convert my image downloaded to a bitmap

             final byte[] byteArray;
             ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
             byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        }



    private class  DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
    }

}
```

Please how can I convert my image downlaoded into a bitmap? Thanks

Comment: *but I am finding it difficult converting it to a bitmap.* could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Your attempt to convert bitmap into a byteArray must happen in onPostExecute, not in onCreate as asynctask is not a blocking call and it will happen asynchronously...

Comment: 'Please how can I convert my image downlaoded into a bitmap?'. You are already doing that in doInBackground. And you let doInBackgroud return that Bitmap which is then set by onPostExcetute - to an ImageView I think.

Answer (score 1):

convert your in stream in string then decode it to bitmap somthing like this :

```
String str = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding); 
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(str, Base64.NO_WRAP);
Bitmap mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

use this code in try block...hope this will help you.

Comment: Please  I dont understand your codes, can you kindly briefly explain to me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

mIcon11 is a Bitmap.

Moreover,

1. Don't use main thread for long-running opperation. Here is good [article](http://jdam.cd/async-android/) about async android;
2. I prefered to download images with [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso);